# python: Syntax error at key=lambda (k,v): (-v,k))

Tags: python

I am doing the lexicon based approach .

However, got error at lambda. The error appeared are "invalid syntax" and "sublist parameters are not supported in 3.x" at this code:

```
def sorted_dic(d):
    ds = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (-v,k))
    return ds
```

Other, I got error here as well . Error is "unexpected token emotion"

```
 emotionss = []
for emotion in predict("Mark Lawrenson", "My boss is a total jackass! He keeps micro-managing me!"):
    print emotion[0] + ': ' + str(emotion[1])
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses around `(k,v)`

Comment: Python 3 does not allow tuple unpacking in the argument list of a `lambda` expression.

Comment: @chepner I guess this is python 2 based in `iteritems`

Answer (score 0):

This worked very well!

```
 def sorted_dic(d):
        ds = sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda k,v: (-v,k))
        return ds
```